# RPi.GPIO: defined output pin not found in /sys/class/gpio

Tags: python, gpio

I have a python3 script which uses RPi.GPIO and defines 2 input pins and 1 output pin like shown below

```
GPIO.setmode(  GPIO.BCM )                # init GPIOs
GPIO.setup( 2, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_UP )
GPIO.setup( 3, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_UP )
GPIO.setup( 4, GPIO.OUT )
```

I want to set the status of the output also from outside of my python script with simple shell commands or manually, but I can't see a GPIO setup for /sys/class/gpio4.
The strange thing is, that RPi.GPIO creates the exports in /sys/class/gpio for the input pins as expected and I can check the status of these pins from a shell without problems.

```
# ls -1 /sys/class/gpio
export
gpio2
gpio3
gpiochip0
unexport

# cat /sys/class/gpio/gpio2/value
1
```

Where does RPi.GPIO define the output pin and how can I access it from outside of python?

Comment: I believe it may use `character device` interface and hence you need to export yourself in your code for others. Also note, that lifetime of the GPIO line ownership is equal to runtime of your script.

Answer (score 0):

I found that the /sys/class/gpio interface is deprecated with new kernels.
Using gpio read|write commands works to get the state of the pins from outside of my python script.